# MS SQL Server Errors/sec

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need some help tracking what is causing some errors reported by the Errors/sec Counter for MS SQL Server 2016.

The counter is showing around 2 errors per 10 seconds however I don't see anything in the event logs or sql server logs.

Count anyone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by saying while "Errors" in this case does sound very bad, informational messages are also considered "Errors" in certain instances - so you're seeing errors/sec counter values but it doesn't necessarily mean all of them are bad.

If you want to track what is happening, I would suggest using [Extended Events](https://itsalljustelectrons.blogspot.com/2016/09/Enhanced-TSQL-Error-Handling-With-Extended-Events.html), since Traces are deprecated and do not gather all of the same data. The link will take you to a post where you can copy and paste, no sense reinventing the wheel here.

It is up to you to decide if these errors warrant more investigation or not. Do be warned, if you're getting 2 errors every 10 seconds that will extrapolate into 720 errors/hour or 17,000 errors a day... I **highly** doubt you want to go over all of them by hand - bucketing them (modifying the query on the blog) can remove most of the *noise*.

Comment: Extended Events helped a bit, I was able to find 3 errors but they happen once in a while, except for a connection error that is happening every 30 seconds.  However, I still don't know what is causing the counter to increment every 10 seconds.

Comment: Found the problem, thank  you!  So it turns out that connection error I mentioned in my previous message is what was causing it.  The Extended Events logged it every 30 seconds because that is when it times out.  However it really was being executed every 10 seconds which is what the Errors/sec counter was recording.  As soon a I resolved the connection error the Errors/sec counter went to 0. Yay!!!!